# Xcode Output is blank when running simulator (7.3.1)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm running an app on the Xcode simulator but nothing is being displayed in the output. If I restart the simulator (shut down simulated device, rebuild app) then I can get logs on the first run, but not on the second or later builds.

I'm using Xcode 7.3.1

I've tried "All Output", "Debugger Output", "Target Output"

I know that logs are printed from my app.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does simulator/xcode gives any alert.
Please share screen shots for better visibility and understanding.

Comment: Does it say "All Output" at the lower left of the console?

Comment: Try (when in the simulator) going to Simulator > reset content and settings. Or try a different simulator, sometimes, for some reason, testing a different device works. Hope that helps!

Comment: @matt, Yes the simulator says "All Output" in the bottom left corner of the console.

Comment: @CoolPenguin , Yes, Reset content and setting doesn't help. Trying a different simulator is a working solution but takes too long to rebuild the app